# Additional shipping fees for specific items...possible?

Tags: shipping, custom-options, shipping-methods

I have a client with a Magento site that we inherited from their original developer and I don't know much about the platform. The client is an online candy store and wanted to know...

"Is there a way we can get something set up in Magento to allow us to check a box if an added fee of $1.99 per item needs to be added to ship chocolate in the summer.  We can go thru the products and check the ones that need this added to, we just need something set up in the back office and something for customers to see when they are viewing the product and checking out letting them know of this chocolate shipping charge."

Can anyone shed some light on the process of adding additional shipping fees for certain products?

Answer (score 0):

Magento has native support for this type of shipping, it is called 'Table Rates'.

Go to

> Admin > System > Configuration > Shipping Methods > Table Rate

Then select your website scope, from the drop down menu in the top left corner.

Then in the table-rates section, you'll see a button to export the CSV. Then edit it to suit your needs.

What you want to use is "Weight vs. Destination" - which will allow you to set a different shipping rate based on the weight attribute on your product. You can also specify a destination if you want, or use * for everything.

Hope this helps.